# Spring cacheable annotation doesn't work before deployment completes

Tags: java, spring, caching, couchbase

I have the following classes and interfaces(simplified to make things clear).

```
@Serivce
class Service1 {

    @Cacheable("cacheName")
    public Metadata preLoadMetadata() {
        // load data from database
    }
}

@Service
class Service2 implements Loader {

    @Autowired @Lazy
    private Service1 service1;

    @Overrride
    public CacheWrapper getCacheWrapper() {
        return new CacheWrapper(() -> service1.preLoadMetadata());
    }
}

interface Loader {
    CacheWrapper getCacheWrapper();
}

class CacheWrapper {

    private Callable callable;

    public CacheWrapper(Callable callable) {
         this.callable = callable;
    }

    public getCallable() {
         return callable;
    }
}
```

The Spring bean responsible for loading the cache at the time of deployment.

```
@Component
class LoadCache {

    @Autowired
    private List<Loader> allLoaders;

    @PostConstruct
    public void load() {
        allLoaders.getCacheWrapper().getCallable().call();
    }
}
```

`preLoadMetadata()` doesn't save the data in the cache but it does execute. After deployment is complete and I call the same method `preLoadMetadata()` again, then it saves the data in the cache.

Why does `@Cacheable` doesn't work at the time of deployment?

If I manually use `put` method of `Cache` to populate cache inside method annotated with `@PostConstruct`, I am able to do it successfully while deployment.

I am using Tomcat as server.
I am using Couchbase cache behind Spring cache abstraction.

Comment: Because it's in the middle of deployment.

Comment: @Kayaman If so, then why doing it programmatically populates the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause for not working of `Cacheable` annotation:
`afterSingletonsInstantiated()` method sets the `initialized` flag to true only when `BeanFactory` has instantiated all the beans. If the `initialized` flag is false, no caching operations are performed. Here, inside the post construct, when we start pre-loading caches, then it is highly probable that `LoadCache` is not the last bean to be instantiated. Hence, no caching operations are performed(while using caching annotations).

Hence, `EventListener` annotation responding to `ContextRefreshEvent` is the best thing to use in this case which ensures that the context has started and then only loading of caches take place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preload your cache I suggest you use an `ApplicationListener` that will execute once your application has started:

```
@Component
public class CacheInitializer implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{

    @Autowired
    private List<Loader> allLoaders;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        allLoaders.getCacheWrapper().getCallable().call();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your idea of using ApplicationListener. But can you throw some light on why Cacheable doesn't work? The cacheManager is instantiated and all caches are ready, but yet Cacheable doesn't work.

Comment: It's very likely that since the beans are still in the initialization phase, the aspectj aspects haven't been enabled yet.

Comment: We can also use @EventListener(value = "ContextRefreshedEvent.class") annotation which would prevent implementing ApplicationListener.

Comment: But I use CTW, so aspectj would not create a problem I guess.